# Why doesn't my program recognize Cin inside a loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, cin, cout

So I'm super new to C++ and I'm trying to get some values from a user ( bunch of numbers), and I want to find the mean median and mode of these numbers. This is how I'm trying to do, but the second cin inside the for loop gets error as

> Error C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mean, max, min, range = 0;
    int numbers[100];
    cout << "please enter the range " << endl;
    cin >> range;
    cout << "please enter the values" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < range; i++)
    {
        cin >> numbers[i] >> endl;
    }
     return 0;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: The error is in the `>> endl` portion of the code.

Comment: Array indices start at 0, not 1. It might not be a problem here, but it will bite hard eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::endl` is not a variable to which you could assign a value. So `cin >> endl` cannot work.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is an output-only I/O manipulator. Change your stream input line to just `cin >> numbers[i];`